# Event Handler Tabbed Web Browser With GeckoFX

Tags: vb.net, browser, tabs, handler, geckofx

I tried to make a tabbed web browser with geckofx. This is my code to make a new tab:

```
    Dim t As New TabPage
    Dim bro As New GeckoWebBrowser
    bro.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    t.Text = "New Tab"
    t.Controls.Add(bro)
    TabMain.TabPages.Add(t)
    TabMain.SelectedTab = t
    bro.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
```

Now, how to handle DocumentCompleted and DocumentTitleChanged in GeckoWebBrowser? I want to show message if DocumentCompleted event triggered and change window title if DocumentTitleChanged event triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the vb.net syntax, but the principle is simple (and it should be fairly simple to transfer from c# to vb)

So, for example:
1) attach an event handler to your browser

`browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;`

2) generate the method that will do what you need:

```
void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            GWB browser = (GWB)sender;
            if (browser.Document == null) return;
            //do anything you wanna do when document is completed
            AnyMethodBasedOnBrowser(browser);

            //e.g. access GUI elements by property binding 
            TabTitle = "Complete";

            //or even alternatively access the control directly
            var TabControl = browser.Parent;
            //etc etc
        }
```

That should do the trick for you!